# MSDN download for Windows Servers 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I am currently looking at the list of available ISOs for Windows Server 2008 on MSDN subscription site and I need to know which one to download for using the Hyper-V feature.

I have the Visual Studio Team System Development Edition with MSDN Premium license.

Follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795645/windows-server-2008-hyper-v-on-x86-processor) on the available ISOs (x86 and X64) with and without Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use x64 Standard, Enterprise, or Data Center.  This information and a lot more is in the [Hyper-V Getting Started Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732470.aspx).